# Error in Java implementing visitor pattern from UML Diagram. -> No enclosing instance of type is accessible

Tags: java, types, uml, visitor-pattern

I am trying to implement an UML Diagram for visitor pattern in Java without specifying the methods.

[image]

I get the following error in the main-method when instantiating DirectorySearchVisitor:

No enclosing instance of type Filebrowser is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Filebrowser (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Filebrowser).

Below is my Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Filebrowser {

    public interface DirectoryVisitor{
        public void enterDirectory(File dir);
        public void leaveDirectory(File dir);
        public void visitFile(File file);
    }

    public class DirectoryPrintVisitor implements DirectoryVisitor{

        @Override
        public void enterDirectory(File dir) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void leaveDirectory(File dir) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void visitFile(File file) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public class DirectorySearchVisitor implements DirectoryVisitor{
        private String extension;
        private List<String> searchList = new LinkedList();
        @Override
        public void enterDirectory(File dir) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void leaveDirectory(File dir) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void visitFile(File file) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void setExtension(String ext){

        }

        public void clearSearchList(){

        }

        public List<String> getSearchList(){
            return this.searchList; 
        }

    }

    public static void traverse(File dir, DirectoryVisitor visitor){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dir = new File("D:/test");

        DirectorySearchVisitor v = new DirectorySearchVisitor();
        v.setExtension(".txt");
        traverse(dir, v);
        List<String> list = v.getSearchList();
    }
}
```

Does it makes sense to split the classes in 2 files or should it work with nested classes?
I also tried first to create an Instance of the outer class and then create an Instance of the inner class, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: For the code I am not sure, for your UML schema, what do you want to model with arrow ? Generalization ? (extends) ? Or Realization ? (implements) ? The method of your interface does not need to be in italic, they are not abstract.

Comment: The upward pointing links are not valid UML.

Comment: You declared all classes such as `DirectorySearchVisitor` as member classes for `Filebrowser`, which means they **require** to be called in context of one of instance methods of the `Filebrowser` object. You are calling it from static method and don't give it a `Filebrowser` object, hence the error. Either make nested classes `static`, or create them after creating the `Filebrowser` instance first.

Comment: So basically, read what compiler errors say.